# How to force @change in vuejs

Tags: html, vue.js

I have :

```
<input type="radio" :name="activity"
                           v-model="activity"
                           :value="1"
                           v-on:change="callProc(data, data2)"
                           required>
```

.....

when the value is already filled from the database, ie the div was shown even if it was not onchanged. It would be something like forcing the onchange. it's possible?

Comment: If you put `activity` as `null` by default in your `data`. The `@change` event will be fired event if the `activity` is populated by the DB.

Answer (score 0):

`@change` is better used to be triggered just when the user acts. Seems like you need call `callProc` before user's action.

You can just call this method after fetch data from database (or inside `created()` hook if you can). Then `v-on:change` will be triggered if user actually changes the value.